# return a value from api for multiple order_id

Tags: java, php, android

I have an api function where I use Multiple order id if the order is from Multiple restaurant. 
This is the response I am getting.

```
["00000303", "00000304"]
```

Here is my code which returns value in Json

```
    $new_order_ids[] = $order_id;
                    if(isset($order_id))
                    {
                        $order_id = intval($order_id);
                        $order_id++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $order_id = 1;
                    }

                    $order_id = str_pad($order_id, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $r_data['order_id'] = $new_order_ids;
$json['order_id'] = $order_info['order_id'];
```

From above code, i get this result `["00000303", "00000304"]`.

and in java, I use this below line of code to get the response.

```
if(response.has("order_id"))
order_id = response.getString("order_id");
```

This gives me `["00000303", "00000304"]`

How can i have order_id like "00000303"?

Comment: proper way means you want result "00000303" only instead of this ["00000303", "00000304"]??

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper way' ? array seems fine to me

Comment: Proper way means 00000303. Yes @curiousMind. In java, i get ["00000303"] for one order

Comment: @Jacky you get the array in response now you just required one for loop by which you can get the single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java code**

```
JSONArray orders=response.order_id;
String orderId;
for(int i=0; i<orders.length(); i++){
    orderId = orders.getString(i);
    // do whatever with the orderId
}
```

**PHP code**

```
function () { 
    $order_ids = array();
    array_push($order_ids, 'order id 1');
    array_push($order_ids, 'order id 2');

    return json_encode({'order_id', $order_id});
}
```

**Update:**

Remember to handle `JSONException` when parsing the JSON response in android

```
try {
    JSONArray orders=response.order_id;
    String orderId;
    for(int i=0; i<orders.length(); i++){
        orderId = orders.getString(i);
        // do whatever with the orderId
    }
}
catch(JSONException err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
try {

    JSONArray orderArray=new JSONArray(response);
    for (int i = 0; i < orderArray.length(); i++) {
        String orderId=orderArray.getInt(i);
        Log.e("orderId", i+"="+orderId);
    }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```